# Source shell script in python

Tags: command-line, bash, python, source

I have a shell script file and a python script file

a shell script file(STEP0.sh) contains this:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="/sc/arion/projects/Variants/annotations/gnomAD"
IN="/sc/arion/projects/Variants/gnomad.exomes.r2.1.1.sites.liftover_grch38.vcf.gz
```

a python script file (STEP11.py) contains this:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
from functools import reduce

f1 = pd.read_csv('$DIR/STEP5_out/vep5.csv')
f2 = pd.read_csv('$DIR/STEP6_out/vep6.csv')
f3 = pd.read_csv('$DIR/STEP7_out/vep7.csv')
```

**What I want to do**

1. I would like to use (by sourcing) the directory from the shell script in the python script as the directory of the csv file. There $DIR means the variable from the shell script.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably do that *before* you invoke python. With a wrapper script (launch_steps.sh):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# automatically export variables
set -a
. ./STEP0.sh
exec python ./STEP11.py
```

And then in python:

- add `import os`
- grab the variables: `dir = os.environ["DIR"]`
- and: `f1 = pd.read_csv(dir + '/STEP5_out/vep5.csv')`